# Creating "Item" definitions

Tags: c++, vector, parameters, directx, game-engine

I am trying to think of a good way to define base-items for a small game I am creating in C++ using DirectX. Right now the structure would look something like:

```
struct itemdef {
    string name;
    ID3DXMesh* mesh;
    vector<IDirect3DTexture9*> textures;
    vector<short> abilities;
};
```

The problem I am having is I essentially want to make an array of these base properties without creating an upper limit for textures or abilities.

Essentially imagine it as having another array of "itemdef"

```
vector<itemdef> itemDefs;
```

and then wanting to add items to this array, either hardcoded or from a file:

```
itemDefs.push_back(NewItem("Wall", Assets.GetMesh(Mesh_Wall), ???, ???));
```

Basically, I have no idea how to put multiple single items into a parameter list for a vector array. The second problem being the need to create two lists in one set of arguments.

So my question is: What should replace the "???" fields in that statement above? Or, failing that, what *better* method should I use to store these basic definitions?

(for clarity: Pointers for textures are obtained virtually the same way as the mesh above was and the "abilities" are just short ints. Although it should be noted that for these definitions both meshes and textures could just be replaced with their enumerations rather than pointers)

Comment: It would help if you added tags for what programming language and API you are using.

Comment: Do you really need pointers to short?

Comment: Haha, oops. Sorry, I was just writing it in as I went. Removed that ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would build up the vector's first as local variables and then send them to the item constructor:

```
vector<IDirect3DTexture9*> tex;
vector<short*> abil;
// fill them with the data you need
itemDefs.push_back(NewItem("Wall", Assets.GetMesh(Mesh_Wall), tex, abil));

itemdef NewItem(const string& name, ID3DMesh* mesh, const vector<IDirect3DTexture9*>& textures, const vector<short*>& abilities)
{
  itemdef retval;
  retval.name = name;
  retval.mesh = mesh;
  retval.textures = textures;
  retval.abilities = abilities;
  return retval;
}
```

Alternatively you could write some function which builds and returns the vector's.

PS: Why do you use some global `NewItem`-function instead of a constructor?

Comment: I am guessing if I wanted to load these definitions from a file I would need the vector-building function.

I probably will use a constructor over a global function. The code above was mainly to show the problem.

Thank you for this reply. I am probably going to alter the mesh and textures to be shorts relating to their array locations in Assets and create two short int vectors for textures and abilities through an appropriate function. Thank you again :)